# Windows unable to find HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, drivers

I need to install Windows on an HP laptop but when I boot with Windows 7 install disc, it keeps reverting to "`Select the driver to be installed`".

I don't understand, why does this happen?

I have installed Linux(*Kali and Ubuntu)* to make sure the HDD is healthy, and everything works fine. Any suggestions?

The laptop is an HP 530 Notebook

Comment: If windows asks that then the installer and the drivers it has loaded probably cannot find the disk. Probably because they cannot find the disk controller. Please go to the firmware (BIOS/EFI) and make sure that normal AHCI mode is selected an not RAID. If RAID is selected either turn it to normal AHCI or put IRSST drivers on a pendrive, DVD or floppy so you can load these during setup, using F6.

Comment: @Hennes Disabled "SATA Native Mode", and still no success.

Comment: What is the dmesg output when you boot Linux (either paste all of it or the relevant parts of SATA controllers/channels/drives".

Answer (score 1):

This can happen for a few reasons, typically because you're either trying to install to a raid or your HD is connected to a newer chipset or a 3rd party controller that Windows 7 doesn't have in it's driver base.

Press the F10 key during boot to get into the bios. 
http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01443329 explains the settings for the bios once inside. Since I don't know the model, I can only assume it's a UEFI model.

The bios will tell you what hardware is present so if need be you can obtain the drivers from HP and install them when need be during the Windows install.

Also, one other thing to check if you're doing this via a USB Device, Windows 7 won't install off of a USB 3.0 port. So if that's what you're doing, try a USB 2.0 port.

Comment: Re USB3: True, unless you slipstream in some USB3 drivers. And since modern desktops often ship without USB1 or USB2 microsoft even provided a tool which helps in most cases.

Comment: The laptop is not UEFI, it came out during the Vista era. Is there a special name for the drivers or are they just the same drivers we download and install (like NVIDIA for example)?

Comment: What's the make / model / complete of the laptop?  Like I know it's not a Pavilion 530, since those seem to be desktops and you said you have a laptop.

Comment: @Matt King I have already given the make and model of the laptop. HP Notebook 530.

Comment: Well I have solved the problem. The issue was that there was a missing HDD driver. Had to request for a HDD driver from HP (since the model had Vista, never knew about Win7).